# C++ - pass a function for an object

Tags: c++, c++11

I'm trying to do something to this effect in C++:

```
class A {
  int get_something();
  int get_something_else();
}

int AccessA(A a, <fn-ptr>) {
    return a.<fn-ptr>
}
```

Basically, I want to pass the function I would like to call on a given object.

Is there a way I can do this in C++?

Thanks,
Azeem

Comment: You are looking for `int (A::*ptr)()`?

Comment: _"Is there a way I can do this in C++?"_ Sure there is. Lookup `std::function` and member function pointers.

Comment: Are you looking to have `class A` execute both its member functions when this `a.<fn-ptr>` is called?

Comment: Thanks! that's exactly what I was looking for.